# how to integrate Flexslider into a WP theme

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have integrated Flexslider into a WP theme using a tutorial. I have activated Thumbnail navigation control, however, all of the thumbnail links are broken.

I have tried inserting the following code into the `<li data-thumb="">` part, but I think I may be missing something in my Slider.php or Functions file.

The code I have tried inserting to create thumbnails is:

```
<li data-thumb="<?php the_post_thumbnail('src'=>''); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check codex page of function [the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

You will need to pass image size as first parameter and it should be called in [The Loop.](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Also post link of Tutorial you are following if possible.